# Set Theory question about the smallest n such that the empty set is in the n-union of Dedekind cuts

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Question:

[image].

Answer:

[image]

I've been trying to understand this question for a while now to no avail. I've looked at the answer but I don't see how you go from one step to the next. I don't even get the first step which says that the union of the set of real numbers is the set of rational numbers. I am completely lost. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The core idea is that a real number _isn't_ a 'thing' in and of itself; it's made up of smaller things. So, e.g., $\pi$ isn't really the number pi; it's the _set_ of all rational numbers smaller than $\pi$.  So $\mathbb{R}$ is a set of _sets_, and all the members of those sets are 'rational numbers' (these are also sets, and that's how you continue down the chain); this means that every member of $\cup\mathbb{R}$ will be a rational number, and you can show that every rational number is a member of that set; therefore $\cup\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{Q}$.

Comment: If you think of $\mathbb{R}$ as a collection of Dedekind cuts of the form $A|B$ where $A = \{r \in \mathbb{Q}: r < x\}$, $B=$ rest of $\mathbb{Q}$ and $x$ is the real number represented by $A|B$, $\cup \mathbb{R} = \{r \in \mathbb{Q}\} = \mathbb{Q}$

Comment: Oh! that's a good explanation thank you. I get the step which follows immediately from that one but then I'm completely lost after that... Do you mind explaining it to me?

Comment: @TommySmith97 since an [ordered pair](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_pair#Kuratowski's_definition) $(a,b)$ is defined as $\{a\},\{a,b\}$, $\begin{align*} \cup \cup \mathbb{R} &= \cup \{\{(a,b): a\in\mathbb{Z}, b\in\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}\}\}  \\ &= \cup \{\{\{a\},\{a,b\}: a\in\mathbb{Z}, b\in\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}\}\}\\ &=   \{\{a\},\{a,b\}: a\in\mathbb{Z}, b\in\mathbb{Z} \setminus \{0\}\}\end{align*}$

Comment: @Darius ∪∪∪ℝ=∪∪{{(,):∈ℤ,∈ℤ∖{0}}}
=∪{{{},{,}:∈ℤ,∈ℤ∖{0}}}
={{},{,}:∈ℤ,∈ℤ∖{0}}
Do you mean this? Sorry for the bad formatting - I just copied and pasted your comment. I really don't get why triple union R equals what you've written. The same applies for the remaining parts i.e. why Z then omega cross omega and so on... I started learning this module a couple days ago and the exam is this Saturday. My fault for leaving it this late.

Comment: @TommySmith97 yes sorry I meant $\cup \cup \cup \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @Darius I finished editing my comment  after you replied (thank you) so I'm not sure if you've seen it. PS I now get triple union R

Comment: @Darius Do you mind explaining quadruple union to 'seven' union R? You'd be a massive help.

Comment: @TommySmith97 Consider $X =\{(1,2),(3,4)\}= \{\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\},\{\{\{3\},\{3,4\}\}\}$. Then $\cup X = \{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}\cup\{\{3\},\{3,4\}\} = \{\{1\},\{1,2\},\{3\},\{3,4\}\}$. Does this help you?

Comment: You have one too many unions. See the line with  $\omega \times  \omega .$ In the line below it, the RHS is also $\omega \times \omega$..... $\cup T$ is the set of the members of the members of $T.$  So if $x\in \cup \Bbb R$ then $x\in r$ for some $r\in \Bbb R$ so $x$ is a member of a Dedekind cut so $x$ is a rational.

Comment: You have likely seen the union of an indexed family. I.e. if $T=\{t_i:i\in I\}$ then $\cup T$ means $\cup_{i\in I}\,t_i.$ But any $T$  can index  itself : Let $I=T$ and  $t_t=t.$  Then $\cup T=\cup_{i\in I}\,t_i=\cup_{t\in T}\,t_t=\cup_{t\in T}\,t.$ The notation $ \cup T$ bypasses the need for an index.

Comment: @Darius I understand that yes. What I don’t understand is how you apply that to triple union R onwards ie why is quadruple union R equal to Z the next one to omega cross omega and so on...